# Is there a precedent for the legal definition of "someone"?

Tags: definition, precedent

It seems strange that there would not be any previous legal cases that explicitly define the legal term "someone" as referring only to a "person".

Yet this was filed on 2023-08-30:

> …
> “Someone else” does not refer to inanimate objects such as a car, a home, an iPhone, or other items in that category.
> Simply stated, if a car or an electronic device is on the verge of being damaged, a person may not take an action that constitutes a criminal offense to prevent the damage and expect that the necessity defense will be available because the defendant would not be able to meet the first requirement of the defense.
> The use of the language “someone else” is just one way to convey the basic idea of the necessity defense and is not an inherent or immutable way to express the requirements of the defense.
> Thus, **the meaning of “someone else” in this requirement should include an animal**, and this amicus brief will show that the necessity defense, as articulated in CALCRIM, applies to actions taken to prevent harm to animals, including agricultural animals.
> …
>
> — [Superior Court of California County of Sonoma — Case No. SCR-721464-1](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2FDxE.io%2Famicusbrief%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR3HDJjqTtezw7UtdlWOhw1PljFyX93qfEkgaQVW01ShTEYWff22Q9z9eEE&h=AT2c9ATWf6z017CptWQ2LarycoMk2IvxxgOQ0uCmAoiq0Hch5BiJ2OZv-5rpLXjUlrZO2ZJGOpflFnQiiUVpPg07Qf3Na8M1Nfs_NmbpagYMzJXiyGEQiyFzL_KiQt1eiHuedSFfa1qr)

Comment: You do realize, don't you, that the document you link to is not a court ruling but rather an argument that someone is making to urge the court to issue a certain ruling.  Also any previous cases defining the term in any context other than that of the necessity defense in California criminal law would be irrelevant to this case.

Comment: I think the fact that it's not an opinion is OP's point, i.e., "how is this argument not already precluded?"

Comment: Your second point is a good one, though. "Someone" has as many definitions as there are laws that use it.

Comment: @bdb484, perhaps there are some subtle nuances from law to law, but do you have any examples of a legal definition substantially different in meaning than the common "*an unknown or unspecified person*"?

Comment: I think that's usually going to be about the definition. The problem comes when you peel it back one layer more and ask what the statute means by "person."

Comment: @bdb484. The term "person" is well defined in most jurisdictions. [Legal person - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_person#:~:text=In%20law%2C%20a%20human%20person,%2C%20Latin%3A%20persona%20ficta).) actually says that "person" *can* apply to an animal in India. Canada has [Persons Day](https://women-gender-equality.canada.ca/en/commemorations-celebrations/womens-history-month/persons-day.html), celebrating the day women were legally declared as persons. The abortion debate is not about whether a fetus is human, but about when it becomes a person. But is a "someone" a person?

Comment: @RayButterworth That's a strange assertion. What is the definition of "person" in the United States?

Comment: @bdb484, the linked article says "*In law, a legal person is any person or 'thing' (less ambiguously, any legal entity) that can do the things a human person is usually able to do in law – such as enter into contracts, sue and be sued, own property, and so on.*". You are a person, and General Motors is a person, but my dog isn't and never will be. [Are Children "Persons"?](https://daily.jstor.org/are-children-persons/) shows that children are persons, even though they can't yet sign contracts or sue.

Comment: I don't actually see that quote anywhere in the article, but I suppose that's not the point, because JSTOR articles aren't the law. Are you aware of an actual law that defines "person" for the United States? I'm virtually certain no such law purports to exist.

Comment: @bdb484, the quotation was from the Wikipedia article.  "Person" is defined by what it can do and what can be done to it: "*Under the law, a person can sue and be sued, can own property, and can enter into contracts. The term "person" includes both natural person and legal person.*" ([US Law | Legal Information Institute | Cornell Law School](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/person). ¶ My original question is based on surprise that whether an animal can be considered a person or that "someone" is the same as a person, seems to have never been decided in court.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that point. All I'm saying is that the reason this isn't settled is that different laws define "person" differently and therefore define "someone" differently. So the question has, actually, been answered in court, but that answer is going to be limited to the context in which it arose.

Answer (score 2):

The brief does not purport that there is a special legal definition of "someone" which includes animals but not inanimate objects. Instead, the brief argues that the common law concept of "necessary" in California includes protection of animals. The brief claim that this position has not been foreclosed by prior California rulings which "speak
in terms of the 'harm or evil sought to be avoided' or 'prevent[ing] a significant evil'". The brief asserts (though without citation of such rulings by courts) that "'Someone else' does not refer to inanimate
objects such as a car, a home, an iPhone, or other items in that category", that is, the courts also have no foreclosed the possibility that defense of iPhone can factor into a necessity defense, but the author's goal is not to expand the concept "someone else" to *that* extent. As the brief states,

> The use of the language “someone else” is just one way to convey the
> basic idea of the necessity defense and is not an inherent or
> immutable way to express the requirements of the defense...
>
> the meaning of “someone else” in this requirement should include an
> animal, and this amicus brief will show that the necessity defense, as
> articulated in CALCRIM, applies to actions taken to prevent harm to
> animals, including agricultural animals

The brief then argues that

> the State of California recognizes that animals are sentient beings
> and that they feel pain and can suffer bodily harm. Further, it is the
> public policy of the State to aid animals in distress, even when doing
> so also involves damage to property or trespassing, and even when the
> animals in question are agricultural animals.

The focus here is on
the Vehicle Confinement Law, the Good Samaritan Laws, and  the Impounded Animal
Law, the pint being to argue that there is a public policy in California to legally assist animals in distress.
As you can see in the quote about "the use of language", the brief is not about meanings of words, it is about the underlying legal and political concepts embodied in law. This is similar to a "legislative intent" argument, except that the necessity defense does not flow from legislative action. The argument does, however, call on presumptions about legislative intent in the case of the Vehicle Confinement Law, which asserts that in this law, there is "a clear recognition that animals can suffer bodily harm
and that preventing that harm is a desired goal". Indeed, there is a statutory requirement under this law that a person who breaks into a vehicle containing an animal must

> remain[s] with the animal in a safe location, out of the elements but
> reasonably close to the vehicle, until a peace officer, humane
> officer, animal control officer, or another emergency responder
> arrives

and if you don't, you can be sued. Finally, there is legislative history that this law was written to include any kind of animal whatsoever, though the author's examples are limited to domesticated (agricultural) mammals.

Comment: Yes, but my basic question isn't about the purpose of the brief itself; it's about only this one statement: "*the meaning of “someone else” in this requirement should include an animal*". Its presence implies that the concept has never been tested in court before, and I find that difficult to believe.